# Can't get my WiFi (D-Link DWA-182 Wireless USB Adapter) running

Tags: wifi, release-juno, usb

I am trying to install WiFi drivers for elementary os on my stationary PC by exchanging downloaded files (ubuntu packages) using a WiFi connection from my laptop.

I downloaded several ubuntu packages (such as rtl8812au-dkms, and dependencies) to get my USB-WiFi Stick running on my stationary PC.

I do not have the possibility to connect via Ethernet, though using my laptop with WiFi connection to transfer downloaded items between two machines using an USB Data Stick.

While trying to install the packages on elementary os on my stationary PC, eventually I'm getting the message that I am probably doing harmful changes. What can I do to install drivers and enable a WiFi connection on my stationary PC?

Answer (score 1):

Before anything, before any input or *sudo* code in Terminal, I believe it is worth checking in the Apps window, start typing **Software** and it will show something like **Software & Updates**.

For me, in the 5th tab, it shows ***Additional Drivers*** and from there I could select an **unknown device** to *use dkms source for the r8812au network driver*.

Hope this helps from a clean install and without internet. If you can, just connect it with a cable or another USB adapter and spare yourself the hassle by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install `rtl8812au-dkms`. Since you don't have a internet connection on that machine you need to download the package on another machine that has internet and then copy it to the other machine. You can do it like this:

On the machine with internet:

```
apt download rtl8812au-dkms && cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*dkms*  ~/Downloads
```

This is going to download and copy the necessary files to your Downloads folder. Please check this line when you execute that command:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
dkms rtl8812au-dkms
```

If there are more packages listed there, please tell me before continuing with the next step. Otherwise it won't work.

Now open your download folder and copy the 2 .deb files that appeared there to the usb stick. The files should contain `dkms` in the name.

Now go to the pc that doesn't have internet and copy those files to any empty directory you want. Then press `right click > Open In > Terminal` to open that folder on the terminal window.

Lastly, install those deb files with `sudo apt install ./*.deb` and reboot your machine :)

Comment: Hey, sorry for my late respond... But to the topic: When I copy the first line you mentioned I get the answer that the package already is installed with the newest version. It is (therefore) not downloaded with the mentioned line. Can you help?

Comment: It should download it. can you try adding a `-f` so it tries to force it? like `sudo apt-get install -f ....`

Comment: Sorry, but I still get the same message.

Comment: Check my answer again. I've updated the command so that you don't get the error. This one works, I've tried it.

Comment: Still, nothing ...

Comment: `cd ~/Downloads && apt download rtl8812au-dkms dkms`